# MastoJS + NextJS API Routes (Serverless): [TypeError]: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, next.js, serverless, next.js13, mastodon

Just tried using [mastojs](https://github.com/neet/masto.js) with nextjs api routes. The mastojs code works if I run it from my local machine via nodejs:

```
import { login } from 'masto';

const masto = await login({
    url: process.env.URL,
    accessToken: process.env.TOKEN,
  });

const status = await masto.v1.statuses.create({
  status: 'Hello from #mastojs!',
  visibility: 'public',
});
```

However, in nextjs api routes it gives me an error. The code in NextJS looks like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { login } from 'masto';

export async function GET() {
  const masto = await login({
      url: process.env.URL,
      accessToken: process.env.TOKEN,
    });
      
  return NextResponse.json({ 
    hello: "world"
  });  
}
```

Just this already throws an error:

> - error node_modules/.pnpm/masto@5.11.3/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs
>   (3822:33) @ EventEmitter
> - error Error [TypeError]: Class extends value # is not a constructor or null
>   at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/masto@5.11.3/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs:3986:38)
>   at Object.(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/masto@5.11.3/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs
>   (/Users/xxx/.next/server/app/api/bots/mastodon/route.js:1982:1)

Any idea what this could be? Does mastojs have problems running in serverless functions?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth filing a bug with `masto` maintainers as the library doesn't work in Next.js out of the box.

I managed to resolve all compilation issues with the following steps:

1. Install optional dependencies:

```bash
npm i bufferutil encoding utf-8-validate
```

2. Apply the following patch with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package):

patches/masto+5.11.3.patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs b/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs
index eb0fb04..7dcae64 100644
--- a/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs
+++ b/node_modules/masto/dist/index.cjs
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@ var ponyfills = require('@mastojs/ponyfills');
 var semver = require('semver');
 var qs = require('qs');
 var changeCase = require('change-case');
-var EventEmitter = require('eventemitter3');
+var EventEmitter = require('eventemitter3').EventEmitter;
 var WebSocket = require('isomorphic-ws');
 
 /**
```

Hope this helps.